Clipboard paste not working in VS Code after copying from Chromium-based browsers
I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code. When I try to paste text into VS Code after copying from certain browsers and applications, the paste operation does not work as expected.
Details

OS: Arch Linux
WM: Hyprland
VS Code Version: 1.89 - 1.92
Affected Applications: Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Vivaldi, Obsidian (AUR)

Steps to Reproduce

Open a Chromium-based browser (e.g., Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Vivaldi) and select some text.
Copy the text using Ctrl+C.
Switch to Visual Studio Code and attempt to paste the copied text into an open file using Ctrl+V.

Expected Result
The copied text should be pasted into the file in Visual Studio Code.
Actual Result
Nothing is pasted when pressing Ctrl+V in VS Code if the text was copied from a Chromium-based browser. However, when checking the clipboard history with Windows+V, the text is visible and selecting it from the clipboard allows it to be pasted into VS Code.

What I've Tried

Restarting Visual Studio Code
Disabling all extensions
Updating Visual Studio Code to the latest version
Changing and restoring keyboard shortcuts for copy and paste (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V) as suggested in various forums
Additional Information:

The issue does not occur when pasting into other applications or when the text is copied from Firefox.
I have also tried copying from the Obsidian app and encountered the same issue.
Question
Has anyone else experienced this issue or does anyone have suggestions for potential solutions or workarounds?
video demonstration of the issue showing the steps and the behavior I am encountering.

With a Mac Mini with Sonoma and VS Code 1.91.1 (Brave Browser), I cant reproduce this issue

seems related https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/218776 but got closed as invalid

probably a html vs. plain text issue. It should not happen if you copy from a textbox, or textarea though. There is a nice addon for copying selected text as plain text for chrome, it's called "Copy As Plain Text".

I created a new user profile, and the copy-paste functionality from edge to vscode works as expected in that profile. This indicates that the problem is likely related to the configuration of my original user profile.

I found a "solution" to my issue with copy-pasting text.
The file ~/.config/code-flags.conf contained the following lines:
--ozone-platform-hint=wayland
--disable-gpu
By removing the line --ozone-platform-hint=wayland, the copy-paste functionality started working again as expected. VSCode now runs under XWayland instead of natively on Wayland, which seems to solve the problem.
Switching VSCode to run under XWayland resolved the clipboard issues. It appears that the configuration forcing VSCode to use Wayland was causing the problem.
